# Is getXXX() method naming convention in java only for accessor methods?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I am teaching students about methods in Java (before they learn objects), so I'm going to be introducing methods using "public static" methods. (This is not my choice. It is how the textbook is organized).

I want to name my methods starting with a verb.

One methods I'm thinking of showing is a getSumOfTwoInts(int, int) method, or a getMaxNumber(int, int) method, or a getAngryMessage(String) method.

However, I know that methods named getXXX() are the convention for naming accessor methods (ie, methods that return the value of some instance variable). If I write my own methods that aren't accessor methods, is it bad style to have them start with the word "get"?

Comment: Why not omit the `get`? `maxNumber(int, int)` is just as descriptive.

Comment: @Andrew Li, Is it not proper style to have all methods start with a verb? Anyhow, I like having a verb there because it emphasizes the idea that methods /do/ some task we want to accomplish. Also, the "get" helps with the idea of the method returning something. Methods that have no return value, I'm likely to use "display" or "print" as my verb.

Comment: I usually use `calcWhatever` or `computeWhatever` for functions that perform computations. There are usually more descriptive verbs for other actions.

Comment: @Hulk , .. so maybe "computeMaxNumber()", .. "supplyAngryMessage()", "computeSumOfTwoInts()"?

Comment: No, just `maxNumber`, `angryMessage`, and `sumOfTwoInts`. That's the way I've always done it and verbs aren't really needed

Comment: Yes, something like that. Perhaps `findMaxNumber` or `findMaximum` for a method that returns the max element of some collection etc.

Comment: Since your question is opinion based, you are getting opinions. Perhaps rephrase?

Comment: The java API itself is not really consistent in this regard. They sometimes prefer brevity over the "Methods should be verbs" recommendation from their styleguide - one example [IntStream.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--) and the other stats methods there, but: [IntStream.findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#findFirst--)

Comment: @AndrewLi man, this is the second time I'm in dnager of getting a question closed / super-downvoted because I'm asking about style / conventions! it seems that asking about proper conventions is usually unwelcome on stackexchange.

Comment: @silph They aren't and asking opinion based questions make them subject to closure

Answer (score 2):

[Java naming conventions from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) state that

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

Nothing is said to disqualify methods that start with the `get` verb. Moreover, there is nothing special about such methods. [Javabean naming convention](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1477673943_e5a8d64edeaa1efebd387f50622a60cd) says that `get` prefix on a public parameterless method returning a value other than `boolean` makes the method a property:

> **8.3.1:** If we discover a matching pair of `get<PropertyName>` and `set<PropertyName>` methods that take and return the same type, then we regard these methods as defining a read-write property whose name will be `<propertyName>`. We will use the `get<PropertyName>` method to get the property value and the `set<PropertyName>` method to set the property value.

As you can see, this does not apply to `getXXX` methods that take parameters; it does not apply to `static` methods, either, so your `getSumOfTwoInts` and `getAngryMessage` are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The name `getXXX()` is an accessor, but that doesn't mean it has to map to anything specific in the internal representation of the object.

As long as the object can return something meaningful for its *interface contract*, whether or not this is backed by a member variable is immaterial.  In fact, requiring that it be so would violate the principle of encapsulation.  All that matters for calling a method `getXXX()` is whether or not the object's specification says such a method is meaningful.

The "principle of least surprise" would hint that such a method should probably return the same value every time it is invoked unless it is meaningful, in the context of the object's specification, for the value to change over time.

Comment: so, my question is actually for static methods, instead of instance methods. so do you think that getXXX() is okay even when it isn't an instance method?